# How to format the xslt in SPD editor with correct outlining?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Maybe a silly question, but I can't figure out how to get the SPD to format my xslt nicly. It is really big, and almost impossible to read when the outlineing is not correct. In my editor, it seems to be lots of spaces and tabs inserted randomly, so the tags don't line up.

Are there some action I can perform to get the code nicly formatted?

Regards

Larsi

Comment: Welcome to SPD ;) First thing I do is spend time tidying up the formatting of XSLT before I dive into whatever I'm doing with it.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was afraid of that answer :-) My approach is to copy the xsl root tag into a new xml file and edit it in vs. Then I atleast can do collapse tags. When I'm done I paste back into vs.

Comment: Good plan. If you have Visual Studio then definitely go for it purely for the lovely CTRL+E,D shortcut :) You'll also get realtime warnings about your XSLT syntax, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has some macros and tools in it to clean up and format code to be more readable.  Within Sharepoint Designer, you can select code blocks, right click, and select Format HTML.  This doesn't work as well as Visual Studio or Notepad++.

Comment: I copy all code whether it's JavaScript/jQuery/XSLT into Notepad++ and dev with that only.  I will then copy my code back into SPD.  SPD is only good for a few things and unfortunately, coding isn't one of them. :/